# R package for calculation of distance to a convex hull from the origin

Tags: r, geometry, distance, convex-hull, convex-optimization

Is there an R package to calculate the distance from the origin to a convex hull with a large number of vertices in xy plane? The distance is defined as the shortest distance from the origin to the points on the edges. I checked the package Geometry but it doesn't seem to work for this problem.

Comment: I would start by using a convex solver. The problem is basically `min ||x||, Ax≥b`. These things typically solve quite easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of a particular package doing that but you may build your own code which can do it. My approach could be: since the coordinates of the convex hull vertices are known and the convex hull edge segments are lines from one vertex to another, you can calculate the perpendicular distances from a point to each line segment and take the minimum distance. I am not sure how you determine the coordinates of the origin of the convex hull, but this approach is applicable to any point tat you decide.